# Android: Combine mobile data and wifi?

Tags: android, wifi

guyz is it possible to combine mobile data and wifi to increase bandwidth.
if anyone have solution please explain but dont be explain about any third party app like speedify. I need a specific solution programatically in android .

Thanks,